# unable to fit image properly in CircleAvatar in ios devices

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple widget `CircleAvatar` which has a child `ClipOval`. I am downloading image from firebase but unable to fit the image properly inside these widget. it shows up with white borders, however it shows fine in android devices after taking and uploading the picture from it.

[image]

```
CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    radius: 65,
    //backgroundImage: NetworkImage(driversInformation.profile_image!),

    child: ClipOval(
        child: Image.network(
            driversInformation!.profile_image!,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                ImageChunkEvent ? loadingProgress) {
                if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null ?
                        loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                        loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                        :
                        null,
                    ),
                );
            },
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: I think it has more to do with the dimensions of the image than iOS vs android. ClipOval makes widgets, as the name suggests, oval. Only square shaped widgets will be circle shaped

Comment: well i did try `fit: BoxFit.fill,` still nothing

Comment: it doesnt work that way.. you have to use backgroundImage